# Extract HTML Table Based on Specific Column Headers - Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to extract html tables from the following [URL](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000120677420000907/mmm3661701-def14a.htm#d366170a083) .

For example, 2019 Director Compensation Table that is on page 44. I believe the table doesn't have a specific id, such as 'Compensation Table' etc.. To extract the table I can only think of matching column names or keywords such as  "Stock Awards" or "All Other Compensation" then grabbing the associated table.

Is there an easy way to extract these tables based on column names? Or maybe an easier way?

Thanks!

I am relatively new at scraping HTML tables.. my code is as follows

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000120677420000907/mmm3661701-def14a.htm'
r = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @BittoBennichan the entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that, using `pandas` `read_html` function using `match` and `attrs` according to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/66740/000120677420000907/mmm3661701-def14a.htm", attrs={'style': 'border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; font: 9pt Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif'}, match="Non-Employee Directors")

print(df)

df[0].to_csv("data.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Output: [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a9438f2e0f1fde539e7391f8ef7f3ded/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - this works. If we took it a step further, do you think its possible to iterate this through a number of different html files. The issue that would arise is if there are multiple tables that include 'Non-Employee Directors' or there isn't uniformity between formatting. For example 3M (as above) may use 'Non-Employee Directors' while Apple may use 'External Directors'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Patriots_25 you can match with `attrs` and position `[]` only if it's always in same position !

Comment: Understood- so if we look at Apple's filing

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312520001450/d799303ddef14a.htm

The same table is included except it has much different column headers. Can you think of any way to universally try to extract these tables?

Comment: @Patriots_25 which table exactly ? share [screen-shot](https://imgur.com/)

Comment: Does this link work for screen shots? https://imgur.com/a/OihTSZR

If it works - see how the data is the same but there isn't uniformity between filers. For example AAPL has all the data in one table... MMM has it broken up into 2 tables

Comment: @Patriots_25 sorry, i couldn't understand your question yet. You've received an answer based on your original post. Now, you do have a different case, you've to open a new question and include full details in order to understand your target.